# Change plain text email into HTML email

Tags: email, email-templates, html

This is in Magento 1.9.x.

I just edited the contents of a transaction email, added some HTML code into it, but the email is still rendering as plain text.

How do I make that email into a HTML email?

Here is how it looks in Magento:

[image]

The email contains HTML tags, but it's template type is Text.

I cannot find anywhere to either (a) change this template type to HTML OR (b) create a new HTML template.

This is the email content:

```
<body>
<img alt="Flamefast" src="http://www.flamefast-gas-safety.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/gas-safety/images/logo.png" />
<h1>Web Enquiry Form</h1>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>{{var data.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td><td>{{var data.email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telephone:</td><td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company:</td><td>{{var data.company}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Interested in:</td><td>{{var data.interest}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quote Required:</td><td>{{var data.request_quote}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info Required:</td><td>{{var data.request_info}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Call-back Required:</td><td>{{var data.request_callback}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Message:</td><td>{{var data.comment}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

And this is what it looks like in my email client. None of the HTML is being rendered. My problem here is I cant find *anything* in Magento's Admin Panel that could create a HTML email or change this to a HTML email.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override config.xml](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/how-to-override-config-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll find all the necessary info here: [How to override config.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/how-to-override-config-xml/10696#10696)

Don't forget to clear the cache and create a new contact email template in the admin (or delete them to use the default HTML template from /app/locale/xx_YY/template/email), as the changes will be visible only in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Very old post but nevertheless I stumbled about this again:

When creating the transactional template it depends on the code which is used whether it will be plain text or html.
So in case you used the standard "contacts" text:

```
Name: {{var data.name}}
Email: {{var data.email}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}
Comment: {{var data.comment}}
```

it will be plain text.

But using

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="action-content">
                        <h1>Hi admin,</h1>
                        <p>{{var data.name}} (contact details: {{var data.email}} {{var data.telephone}}) asked a question on your website: </p>
                        <p class="highlighted-text">
                        {{var data.comment}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

will result in an html template.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml

Note: You can create your own module and override the contact module config.xml file OR copy the original file to app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml first then edit it.

```
<email>
   <contacts_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
       <label>Contact Form</label>
       <file>contact_form.html</file>
       <type>text</type>
   </contacts_email_email_template>
</email>
```

Replace to

```
<email>
   <contacts_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
       <label>Contact Form</label>
       <file>contact_form.html</file>
       <type>html</type>
   </contacts_email_email_template>
</email>
```

Comment: Editing the core is a very bad practice as changes will most likely be overriden when upgrading Magento. Update your answer so you suggest to copy the original file to `app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml` first then edit it