# Contact us e-mail edit

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, html, contact-us, edit

I have edit to html code in `magento/app/locale/en_US/template/email/contact_form.html`

but when i get email it gives row html.

code is as bellow in html

```
<!--@subject Contact Form@-->
<!--@vars
{"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone",
"var data.comment":"Comment"}
@-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>{{var data.name}}</td> 
</tr></br>
<tr>
<td>Email: </td><td>{{var data.email}}</td> 
</tr></br>
<tr>
<td>Telephone: </td><td>{{var data.telephone}}</td> 
</tr></br>
<tr>
<td>Comment: </td><td>{{var data.comment}}</td> 
</tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

any solution for this ?

Comment: add screenshot or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to change the config.xml setting (`type`) of `Contacts` module of default Magento.

For that refer the below link on how to override `config.xml` using a custom module approach:

[How to override config.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/how-to-override-config-xml/10696#10696)

Firstly create a module-declaration file like below for you module:

**app/etc/modules/[Namespace]_[Module].xml - the declaration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Contacts /><!-- so the config is loaded after the one from Mage_Contacts -->
            </depends>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then you need module's config file as below:

**app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml - the configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <template>
            <email>
                <contacts_email_email_template>
                    <type>html</type><!-- same xpath as in the original config file -->
                </contacts_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now your email templates are of type `html` by default for `Contacts` module.

**Hope this makes it clear**